# How to upload BUFFER of image to any website with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, buffer, puppeteer

Here's what I know how to do:

- Download an image from somewhere like imgur, capture it as a buffer, save to disk
- Write an image from disk to a page using [elementHandle.uploadFile(path)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths)

However, this solution only works on my local machine. I'm looking to run puppeteer in the cloud, which means that I won't have access to a static disk with file paths. What I'm trying to do, therefore, is omit the disk as a middleman. Once I have the image as a buffer, I want to just directly upload that buffer into the input. I figured that the source code for [elementHandle.uploadFile(path)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths) would be a good place to start, as I'm pretty much just looking to peel back a layer of abstraction. However, I can't find it in puppeteer's github

Answer (score 2):

Here are the basic steps:

1. encode your data with Base64
2. pass it over the wire with `page.evaluate`
3. decode it into a `Uint8Array`
4. wrap the array with the `File` constructor
5. put the file in a `DataTransfer` object to create a `FileList`

#### File inputs

In your case, you'll need to pass an `ElementHandle` to the `input[type="file"]` element in question, so you can set its `files` property.

```
await page.evaluate(
  async (encodedImage: string, mimeType: string, fileInput: Element) => {
    const rawImageString = atob(encodedImage)
    const rawImageBytes = new Array(rawImageString.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < rawImageString.length; i++) {
      rawImageBytes[i] = rawImageString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    const image = new File([new Uint8Array(rawImageBytes)], '', {
      type: mimeType,
    })

    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
    dataTransfer.items.add(image)
    
    fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files
    fileInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }))
  },
  encodedImage,
  mimeType,
  fileInput
)
```

#### Drag and Drop

In my case, I wanted to simulate a `drop` event.

```
await page.evaluate(
  async (encodedImage: string, mimeType: string, dropArea: Element) => {
    const rawImageString = atob(encodedImage)
    const rawImageBytes = new Array(rawImageString.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < rawImageString.length; i++) {
      rawImageBytes[i] = rawImageString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    const image = new File([new Uint8Array(rawImageBytes)], '', {
      type: mimeType,
    })

    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
    dataTransfer.items.add(image)

    dropArea.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('dragenter', { dataTransfer }))
    dropArea.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('drop', { dataTransfer }))
  },
  encodedImage,
  mimeType,
  dropArea
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const downloadImgFromUrl = async (url, dest) => {
    // Create an empty file where we can save data
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);

    // Using Promises so that we can use the ASYNC AWAIT syntax
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            uri: url,
            gzip: true,
        }).pipe(file).on('finish', async () => {
            console.log(`Image downloaded from Storage`);
            resolve();
        }).on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Image download from URL failed: ${error}`);
    });
}

    await page.waitForTimeout(1000)
    const [filechooser] = await Promise.all([
      page.waitForFileChooser(),
      page.focus("#attach_file_photo"),
      page.click('#attach_file_photo')
    ])

    await downloadImgFromUrl(imgUrl, path.join(os.tmpdir(),'uploadimg.png'))

    await filechooser.accept([path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'uploadimg.png')])
```

Comment: You missed this part: "I'm looking to run puppeteer in the cloud, which means that I won't have access to a static disk with file paths."